# ssh2_scp_send: fails, perhaps because of unknown remote dir

Tags: php, sftp, scp

I'm using ssh2_scp_send to transfer a file from one server to another via SFTP. Although I can confirm access to the remote server and can transfer files using a GUI application (FileZilla), my ssh2_scp_send call is failing.

I think this may be because I don't know (and don't easily have access to find out) the full path of the remote server. I assumed that if I just pass the filename it would default to the parent directory the user is allowed access to.

```
$conn = ssh2_connect('domain', 22);
$auth = ssh2_auth_password($conn, 'user', 'password');

if ($auth) {
  //send the file
  $send = ssh2_scp_send($conn, $file, $data['xml_filename']);
}
```

I tried using `ssh2_exec($ssh_conn, 'ls -la');` to retrieve the directory and try to figure out the location, but that fails (the access credentials I have don't permit SSH commands apart from SFTP).

My questions:

1. is there an easy way to find out the full remote path?
2. is there a way to tell ssh2_scp_send to just use the default destination?
3. what other things should I troubleshoot? I'm only guessing that the above is the issue -- it may be something totally different.

Answer (score 1):

`ssh2_scp_send` doesn't do SFTP - it does SCP. You can't do SCP without shell access.

If you're insistent on using libssh2 vs phpseclib then you'll have to use the `ssh2.sftp://` fopen wrapper and then do `fwrite()` or `fputs()`.

As for getting the default full remote path...  `ssh2_sftp_realpath('.')` should do the trick.

Comment: yes, that's exactly what I found. I was able to transfer it by initializing ssh2_sftp and then using file_get_contents/file_put_contents